# Why does changing this image's height to be equal to the document's height fail?

Tags: jquery, css

So in a simple page, there is a `div` containing an `img`. The document would presumably be the same height as the `image`. However, this is not the case. The document is slightly larger depending on the environment. See this **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2gftz/3/)** to see an example. Basically what happens is if the image is set to the document height, then the document height changes.

In case the jsfiddle is no longer available, here is the setup:

html

```
<div><img id="img" src="http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/138/overrides/save-the-ocean-tips_13821_600x450.jpg" /></div>​
```

js

```
$(function(){
 alert("Image Height Before Assignment: " + $("#img").height()); 
 var docH = $(document).height();
 alert("Document Height Before Assignment: " + docH);
 $("#img").height(docH);
 alert("Image Height After Assignment: " + $("#img").height()); 
 alert("Document Height After Assignment: " + $(document).height());
});
```

​

​

**Why can't an image be set to the document height like this, without changing the document height?**

**How can an image be set to the document height without changing the document's height?**

Comment: Please note, jsfiddles don't last, so this question will become meaningless.

Comment: @LeeTaylor - Post that on meta if you have an issue with jsfiddle.

Comment: It's a common criticism of jsfiddle. Allow the question and answer to be of use in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed that by adding `align="absmiddle"` to the image

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/2gftz/6/)

Comment: This does work, but is there a more standardized way of doing it?

Comment: I have tried `vertical-align: middle` but it didn't worked for me, that's why I suggested this solution

Answer (score 1):

It has something to do with the HTML DTD. When I changed it to `HTML 4.01 Transitional`, all alerts gave the same value. `HTML 5` and `HTML 4.01 Strict` both change the document height, as you said.

'Hope this helps to track down the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Using `align="absmiddle"` is bad form and non standardized. I had asked haynar1658 to change his answer to reflect what I found as the solution due to looking for a more standardized version of `align="absmiddle"`. What I came across was the css property **`vertical-align:middle;`**. Here is a solution in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2gftz/8/).

For those who are afraid or critical of jsfiddle, here is the code:

html

```
<div><img id="img" src="http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/138/overrides/save-the-ocean-tips_13821_600x450.jpg" /></div>​
```

css

```
/*
This will ensure the document height doesn't change
*/

#img
{ 
 vertical-align:middle;   
}​
```

js

```
//Display Image height, then document height, then change image height and show that the change no longer affects the document height
$(function(){
 //Show Image height before
 alert("Image Height Before Assignment: " + $("#img").height());

 //Get Document Height
 var docH = $(document).height();
 //Show Document Height
 alert("Document Height Before Assignment: " + docH);
 //Assign image height
 $("#img").height(docH);
 //Show image height
 alert("Image Height After Assignment: " + $("#img").height());
 //Show document height
 alert("Document Height After Assignment: " + $(document).height());
});
```

​

Answer (score -1):

I Would suggest you to create a CSS like this to remove all extra from the body

```
body{
 margin:0px;
 paddin:0px;
 border:0px;
}
```

The body tag has its own proprety.